# Extracting JSON in pandas column to separate columns while handling rows with None

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe called df that contains twitter tweets created by taking the twitter json and loading it into the dataframe. I am trying to extract the interesting information. The coordinates column is mostly None, but sometimes it contains GeoJSON in this format:

```
{'coordinates': [21.425775, 8.906141], 'type': 'Point'}
```

Here 21.425775 refers to the longitude and 8.906141 refers to the latitude. I would like to extract the latitude and longitude into separate columns. Unfortunately my pandas skills are more towards the beginner level, so I am not sure how to do find and substring; also there seems to be better ways as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113449/convert-geo-json-with-nested-lists-to-pandas-dataframe) question which I don't fully understand.

An example of the dataframe is:

```
  coordinates
0 None
1 {'coordinates': [21.425775, 8.906141], 'type': 'Point'}
```

How can I extract the information in the nested JSON column into separate pandas columns while gracefully handling the None values in the other rows?

Comment: Can you post a sample data?

Comment: {'coordinates': [21.425775, 8.906141], 'type': 'Point'} is a sample, another sample would be None

Comment: Can you show a print of `df`? I am not able to understand how the column is...

Comment: Added example data to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `'coordinates'` is a list then you can use `tolist()` with `pd.DataFrame`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'coordinates': [{'coordinates': [21.425775, 8.906141], 'type': 'Point'}, None]})
df['temp'] = df['coordinates'].apply(lambda x: x.get("coordinates") if x else [np.nan, np.nan]).dropna()
df[['longitude','latitude']] = pd.DataFrame(df.temp.values.tolist(), index= df.index)
df.drop('temp', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                         coordinates  longitude  latitude
0  {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [21.425775...  21.425775  8.906141
1                                               None        NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Gives me ValueError: Columns must be same length as key, presumably because of the 'type': 'Point' part.

Comment: Or possibly the None part

Comment: Updated snippet

Comment: Thanks! Works nice. Why does it need the dropna part?

Comment: You are welcome :) and you are correct...you do not need dropna()